# git wont allow me to create empty directory

Tags: git

My app contains a directory X.  Inside directory X all the files will be automatically generated by the scripts, but directory X needs to be there.  I have added the following to the .gitignore and it does not create an empty directory when I do the commit.  How can I get it to just create and empty directory?
/myApp/dirX/somestuff.  I just need /myApp/dirX to be created.

```
.*
dirX/*
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+track+empty+directory

Comment: Add and commit `dirX/.gitignore`